# A manifold admits a nowhere vanishing volume form if and only if it is orientable?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

on this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form) article, it is said :

> A manifold admits a nowhere vanishing volume form if and only if it is
>   orientable

I don't really understand why. Isn't $dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^n$ always a nowhere vanishing? Indeed, for me we should have $dx^1_p \wedge ... \wedge dx^n_p \neq 0 \forall p$ since $\{dx^1_p,...,dx^n_p\}$ is a basis of $T_p^*M$, no?

Also another question :
If $X_1,...,X_n$ is a vector field such that $X_{1p},...,X_{np}$ are linearly independent for all $p$, does this imply that $dx^1_p \wedge ... \wedge dx^n_p(X_{1p},...,X_{np}) \neq 0 \forall p$?

Comment: Note that $dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n$ is defined locally and depends on the choice of coordinates. And you cannot define coordinates globally except in trivial cases.

Comment: @Mindlack Sorry, I don't get your point, could you expand a bit?

Comment: How would you define $dx^1 \wedge dx^2$ on the 2-sphere for instance?

Comment: I chose some charts $(U,(x^1,x^2))$ around each point $p$ no? I don't understand

Comment: You need to define it on the whole sphere, not on some charts. @roi_saumon

Comment: Yes, this is the point: your coordinates are local, they are only defined in charts. And the corresponding $dx^1 \wedge dx^2$ at each $p$ will depend of which chart you took. So you will not have one well-defined $2$-form at each point, or if you do, there is no trivial way to make sure it is smooth, or even continuous. If you wish, orientability corresponds to being able to « glue together » enough nowhere-vanishing forms defined in different charts.

Comment: Oh,thanks, I think I get it. The object that we create will be be nowhere vanishing but not smooth so not a form.

Comment: But then in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we would have no problem of gluing it if we take the standard atlas $\{\mathbb{R}^3, Id_{\mathbb{R}^3}\}$ so $dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ would be a non-vanishing form (so an orientation form) here right?

Comment: What you say about $\mathbb R^3$ is true. However, it is quite rare for an $n$-manifold to possess an atlas having only a single coordinate chart. In fact that holds if and only if the manifold is diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. In particular, it is *never* true for compact manifolds.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025086/partition-of-unity-and-volume-form-on-a-manifold

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252068/non-vanishing-k-form-on-a-k-manifold-in-mathbbrn-implies-orientability

Comment: The easiest way I know how to construct an oriented volume form on an oriented manifold is to use a Riemannian metric.

Answer (score -1):

Y will separe the questions.

1)Isn't $dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$ always a nowhere vanishing?

No, $dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$ is only locally defined.

2)Indeed, for me we should have $dx_{1p}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{np}\neq0, \ \forall p$ since $\{dx_{1p},...,dx_{np}\}$ is a basis of $T^∗pM$, no?

No, because the same reason of the last question.

3)If $X1,\dots,Xn$ is a vector field such that $X_{1p},\dots,X_{np}$ are linearly independent for all $p$, does this imply that $dx_{1p}\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{np}(X_{1p},...,X_{np})\neq0, \ \forall p$?

Yes, if $p$ is in the domain of the chart.